# How to convert DataGridView Column from string to decimal?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, valueconverter

I'm hoping to find a simple way to convert an entire column in my `datagridview` from a `string` data type to a `decimal`. Something simple like this maybe?

```
DataGridView1.Columns(4).ValueType = Decimal
```

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never however:

```
   DataGridView1.Columns(4).ValueType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
```

Incase anyone else is having problems, this should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `typeof()`. Like this:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(4).ValueType = typeof(Decimal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `ValueType` property of the grid view column is a `Type` object, then try using `GetType()`, like this:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(4).ValueType = GetType(Decimal)
```

Comment: When I implement this and step through the debugger its saying that the boolean value is false. So I guess this statement is asking whether or not its a decimal, not converting the string value to a decimal.